# Extract text of link with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
var code = '<span class="category-str-list">
<a href="link1.html">Spas</a>,<a href="link2.html">Massage</a></span>';
```

How can I get the following string?

```
var activities = 'Spas, Massage';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just parse it as HTML and get the text content ?

```
var activities = $(code).text();
```

```js
var code = '<span class="category-str-list"><a href="link1.html">Spas</a>,<a href="link2.html">Massage</a></span>';

var activities = $(code).text();

$('body').html(activities)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: +1 for the first use of the interactive code snippet I've seen

Comment: @APerson - It's pretty cool, still trying to figure everything out, but for small code snippets like this, it's great.